# Error when trying to join two tables in Laravel 5.2, for a search query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What I'm trying to do is, put together a search query by joining two tables together. I have a very simple fictional Real Estate site, where a user can search for listings using multiple options, such as searching by city. The way I have it set up is I have a `City` model and table, which contains a list of cities and a Listing model, controller, and table.

The `city` table is set up with these fields `id` `name`. And for the `listings` table, the `city_id` field connects with `id` field in the `city` table. On my homepage, I have an option where a user types in a city, the results are sent to a results page with all or any listings from that city using the tables from above. This is where I'm running into problems.

This is the error I get when I run the query:

`Trying to get property of non-object`

Here's the code for the form on the homepage:

```
index.blade.php

 <form action="/search" method="GET" role="search">
   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <div class="form-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="search-query" name="q" placeholder="Search citys" autocomplete="off">
          </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SEARCH</button>

  </form>
```

Here's my controller that does the query (`listingcontroller`)

```
public function listingsresults()
    {

      $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
      $listing = Listing::join('cities', 'listings.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
                         ->select('listings.city_id', 'cities.name')
                         ->where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
                         ->paginate(8);

      if (count ( $listing ) > 0)
        return view ( 'front-end/listingsresults' )->withDetails ( $listing )->withQuery ( $q );
      else
        return view ( 'front-end/listingsresults' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );


    }
```

My Listing Model:

```
class Listing extends Model
{

    //
      protected $fillable = [

        'street',
        'city_id',
        'state_id',
        'price',
        'beds',
        'baths',
        'sqft',
        'descrip',
        'category_id',
        'user_id',
        'state_id',
        'fullpic_id',
        'extrapicone_id',
        'extrapictwo_id',
        'extrapicthree_id',
        'extrapicfour_id',
        '',

      ];

      // protected $primaryKey = 'id';

      public function user(){

          return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

      }

      public function state(){

          return $this->belongsTo('App\State');

      }

      public function city(){

          return $this->belongsTo('App\City');

      }

      public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

      }

      public function fullpic(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\PhotoListing');

      }

}
```

My City Model:

```
class City extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

}
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error? I'm not sure if it is because I'm not structuring my query right or not. Also is this the best way to structure the Models, Controllers, and Views I ask because I'm still trying to get a hang of Laravel, and MVC in general.

Comment: Does it mention a file and line number in the error somewhere?

Comment: Yeah this the rest of the error I should've posted that as well `ErrorException in 99348b1eaf68d393c53f802beafeddfb706d328c.php line 120:`                                                                                            
 Line 120 I believe is in reference to this part of my controller :               if (count ( $listing ) > 0)
        return view ( 'front-end/listingsresults' )->withDetails ( $listing )->withQuery ( $q );

Comment: Use the Laravel helper function `dd(listings)` to see what the variable is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "to see what the variable is" I ran the helper function and I got would the correct number of array items in the collection, for the city I searched for. Meaning if I expected to see, for instance, four results for the city of Agawam I get four items in the array (#items: array:4).